# How to get text from search field?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm making a basic web browser to start me off and I would like to add some new features. However, I can't get the text from the urlbar (which is just a searchbar) stored in a variable. Could someone please help?

Here's my zseAppDelegate.h file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface zseAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSSearchField* searchfield;
@end
```

Here's my zseAppDelegate.m file:

```
#import "zseAppDelegate.h"

@implementation zseAppDelegate
@synthesize searchfield,window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSString * searchf = [searchfield, stringValue]
};

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSSearchField` inherits from `NSTextField`, which is an `NSControl`. That implements [`stringValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSControl/stringValue).

So, e.g.

```
NSString *searchFieldValue = [searchField stringValue];
```